# How can I sandbox wine itself, and all wine applications?

Tags: linux, sandbox, restrictions

I don't want wine accessing my ext4 partition which is typically the `Z:` drive. How can I restrict or sandbox wine?

Comment: Is there anything special with wine so that you cannot use [existing sandbox methods](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+sandbox+application) for applications, i.e. container, firejail, AppArmor, virtual machines, ... ?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/714561/how-to-use-wine-with-more-security

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[sandwine](https://github.com/hartwork/sandwine) does not block access to `Z:\` altogether but limits *its content*.  Try e.g. `sandwine CMD /C DIR 'Z:\' "Z:\\home\\${USER}\\"` to see it in action. The main readme has more details on what is exposed by default. Please be sure to also check the readme section on its threat model.